# Percentage img height in table when td height in percentage too, Chrome

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, html-table

I found some problems when trying to set img-tag height in % when it in td-tag specifically in chrome... I want img-tag height be related to parent element (td-tag in this case).  Very simplified code example will look like following:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table class="height-50">
        <tbody class="height-100">
            <tr>
                <td class="height-50">
                    <img class="height-30" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="height-50">
                    <img class="height-30" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}        
table
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}        
td
{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}        
.height-100
{
    height: 100%;
}
.height-50
{
    height: 50%;
}
.height-30
{
    height: 30%;
}
```

It looks like chrome sets img-tag height according to image height but not to parent container height, IE looks good to use td-tag height to set img-tag height. Where I'm have an issue?

Comment: Definitely something wrong there. If you take the image out of the table altogether, Chrome does show it at 30% of the body height, so I don't know why it would use 30% of its own height when in a table. Must do more testing. Oh, and in Firefox, although the heights are OK, it displays the table cells as if the image is still 600px wide. Nice.

Comment: @mr-lister thank you for spending your time to help me with this issue, I really appreciate it.